# openstack npm pkgcloud createImage() function not working

Tags: openstack, orchestration, pkgcloud

I am trying to create an image of an instance in openstack using npm pkgcloud.
For this I am using the code as below:

```
var openstack_client_compute = null;
openstack_client_compute = pkgcloud.compute.createClient({
    provider: PROVIDER, // required
    username: USERNAME, // required
    password: PASSWORD, // required 
    region: REGION,
    authUrl: AUTH_URL // required
});
options = {
    name: 'image1',  // required
    server: '0e4d56a2-173a-425d-befd-cec366605522'  // required
};
openstack_client_compute.createImage(options, function(err, image){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(image);
});
```

I am getting the following error :

> name: 'Error',
>     provider: 'openstack',
>     failCode: 'Service Unavailable',
>     statusCode: 503,
>     href: 'http://controller:8774/v2.1/6af81940df89199f088beba7d93/servers/0e4d56a2-173a-425d-befd-cec366605522/action',method: 'POST',
>     headers:
>      { server: 'squid',
>        'mime-version': '1.0',
>        date: 'Mon, 09 Apr 2018 07:21:15 GMT',
>        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
>        'content-length': '3012',
>        'x-squid-error': 'ERR_DNS_FAIL 0',
>        'x-cache': 'MISS from lproxy',
>        'x-cache-lookup': 'MISS from proxy:8080',
>        connection: 'close' },

Note : other functions such as createStack deleteStack getStack  etc are functioning properly

It is showing the error that unable to resolve host name (controller is not getting resolved to IP) the code is failing due to that.
Any possibility that a change in openstack configuration may resolve it.
If yes what changes are needed?

Comment: Someone with a possible solution on how to fix this, do answer?